# Print string without sub-string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a Logfile that has a format that looks like this:

```
[Time] [mmm] [DATA] [rule] [a.a.a.a]
[Time] [ppp] [DATA] [rule] [a.a.a.a]
[Time] [mmm] [DATA] [rule] [c.c.c.c]
```

In cant' find a way to print this string without a specific sub-string. I want to be able to print the whole string output without the sub-string line that matches `[mmm]` and `[a.a.a.a]`. The final output would be:

```
[Time] [ppp] [DATA] [rule] [a.a.a.a]  
[Time] [mmm] [DATA] [rule] [c.c.c.c]
```

Do I use the index module with two subtrings or use grep in someway? Am I looking at this the wrong way? Any help is much appreciated!!!

In my perl script I have a section that searches for this and prints this section as a string:

```
sub Section
{
    my @event_rule = ("A", "B", "C");

    foreach (@event_rule)
    {
                    my $result1 = `fgrep -h 'DATA' $logfile1 | grep "$_" | head -n10`;
                    if (length $result1)
                    {
                        print "$result1\n";
            }
            }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean "[mmm] and [a.a.a.a]" or "[mmm] **or** [a.a.a.a]"?

Comment: @choroba i think it's and.

Comment: Its [mmm] and [a.a.a.a] @choroba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for external programs like `grep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @rule  = ('[mmm]', '[a.a.a.a]');
my $regex = join '.*', map quotemeta, @rule; # Create one regular expression from the "rules".
$regex    = qr/$regex/;                      # Compile it.

my $c = 0;
while (<>) {
    $c += print if /DATA/ && ! /$regex/;
    last if $c > 9;                          # Only print the first 10 lines.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
grep -P "(?m)^(?!.*\[m{3}\].*\[a(?:\.a){3}\]).*$" file
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/15

Answer (score 0):

If the order of `mmm` and `a.a.a` is same then you could use the below,

```
grep -v '.*\[mmm\].*?\[a\.a\.a\.a\]' file
```

Use this if you don't know the order.

```
grep -P '^(?=.*\[mmm\])(?=.*?\[a\.a\.a\.a\]).+(*SKIP)(*F)|.+' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qP3sJ8/1)

You could use the same regex in perl,

```
perl -lne 'print if /^(?=.*\[mmm\])(?=.*?\[a\.a\.a\.a\]).+(*SKIP)(*F)|.+/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
^(((?!a.a.a.a).)*mmm((?!a.a.a.a).)*)$|^(((?!mmm).)*a.a.a.a((?!mmm).)*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vZ1qP2/1)

The preceding regex will match a string that is contain `mmm` but not `a.a.a.a` or a string that is contain `a.a.a.a` but not `mmm`.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple approach without using `map` or `grep`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    print "$_\n" unless ($split[1] eq '[mmm]' and $split[4] eq '[a.a.a.a]');
}


__DATA__
[Time] [mmm] [DATA] [rule] [a.a.a.a]
[Time] [ppp] [DATA] [rule] [a.a.a.a]
[Time] [mmm] [DATA] [rule] [c.c.c.c]
```